# How to make reverse_lazy() lazy for arguments too?

Tags: django, django-urls, lazy-evaluation

### Introduction

For a particular need (django-jqgrid), I define a class (representing a `Grid`) where I have to provide an `url` attribute. Since I use only reversed URLs (nothing statically defined), I use `reverse_lazy()` for this matter.

This works great as long as I do not have to pass an argument to `reverse_lazy()`. However, if I want to make that `Grid` specific to an object (here, a `DocumentSet`), this `url` arguments needs to be also specific to that object, and so I need to provide an argument to reverse_lazy().

On runtime, I can access the `DocumentSet` because I defined it as an attribute on the object, and I ensure that the first function called on this `Grid` takes this object as an argument, and sets the attribute correctly.

### First attempt

#### Code

I tried using this code :

```
class DocumentGrid(JqGrid):
    documentset = None
    model = Document
    url = reverse_lazy('document-grid-handler', kwargs = {'pk' : documentset.id, })

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        return self.documentset.documents
    def get_json(self, request, documentset):
        self.documentset = documentset
        return super(DocumentGrid, self).get_json(request)
```

#### Error

But of course, this fails when the file is imported because `NoneType object has no attribute 'id'`.

### Second attempt

#### Code

So I tried using `django.utils.functional.lazy()`, by adding this trivial and stupid function to my model :

```
def get_id(self):
    return self.id
```

And by using this code :

```
class DocumentGrid(JqGrid):
    documentset = DocumentSet
    model = Document
    url = reverse_lazy('document-grid-handler', kwargs = {'pk' : lazy(documentset.get_id, int), })

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        return self.documentset.documents
    def get_json(self, request, documentset):
        self.documentset = documentset
        return super(DocumentGrid, self).get_json(request)
```

#### Error

Now the file is imported correctly, without Django complaining. **However**, at runtime, I get the following error :

```
Reverse for 'document-grid-handler' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'pk': <function get_id at 0x1a07410>}' not found.
```

### Conclusion

**Is this the correct way to go, but I'm making a small mistake ? Or did I misunderstood everything about lazy evaluation and should take a completely different approach and rewrite `reverse_lazy()` ?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`django.utils.functional.lazy()` return you a lazy-evaluated callable, in other words it gives you a function that will return lazy value.

See example:

```
l = lazy(lambda : 42, str)
unicode(l)  # returns u'<function <lambda> at 0x3a5bcf8>'
lazy_value = l()
unicode(lazy_value)  # returns u'42'
```

However if you are replacing the `self.documentset` field in your `get_json` function you can get wrong results with your lazy call. As it will use an old `DocumentSet`.

For `JqGrid` there is another solution. `JqGrid` provides you the `get_url` method, by default it just returns `self.url`. But you can override this behaviour:

```
class DocumentGrid(JqGrid):
    documentset = None
    model = Document
    url = None

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        return self.documentset.documents

    def get_json(self, request, documentset):
        self.documentset = documentset
        return super(DocumentGrid, self).get_json(request)

    def get_url(self):
        return reverse('document-grid-handler', kwargs = {'pk' : self.documentset.id, })
```

Comment: Works flawlessly, and thanks for the explanation about lazy-evaluated callables.